# Need Help with Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, components

Hello I am new to Joomla and want to create a functionality such as there will be tutors added on the site who will be teaching the site users i.e. provide some type of guidance through chat/video call. Tutors are themselves a user who will be guiding the site users. 
Tutor will place his availability on a calendar and a user can book a session with tutor for particular time by making payment.

Can anyone please let me know what will i have to do for this? Do i need to develop a joomla component for this functionality or should i go for joomla module?

Also is there any such pre-built component which can be useful to me. Your suggestion will be really helpful.

Regards
- Atul

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I did a little looking around and there are several extensions that allow you to offer video conferencing within Joomla. Most of them are commercial extensions, but well worth the price versus paying to have something custom developed. Take a look here -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/video-conference

Comment: Thanks Brent,
Actually along with the chat functionality i also wanted to know if there is any component available which has the functionality similar to the one described above so that i can use the same along with some modifications. Or if not available then how should i proceed to achieve the same? Would i need to build a component or a module?

Thanks